# How to execute an action automatically after permission granted in jetpack compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have a button to activate system camera with Intent in my app. I want to achieve a permission logic as the way it is usually done.

1. When launching the app at the first time, pressing the button leads to a default permission request dialog.
2. If permission is granted, it will activate system camera immediately.
3. If not, it will ask again.
4. Then, if is is denied for the second time, the dialog will never pop up.(Which is the default logic of Android)
5. However, if the user keeps clicking the button, it will present a dialog asking if the user want to go to the permission setting sheet of this app with a link.

Now, mine still lacks feature 2 and 5. It won't go to the camera automatically. And I don't know how to achieve 5.

Here is my code.

```kotlin
@OptIn(ExperimentalPermissionsApi::class)
@Composable
fun CameraButton(context: Context = LocalContext.current) {

    val permissionState = rememberPermissionState(
        permission = Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
    )
    Button(
        onClick = {
            if (permissionState.status.isGranted) {
                context.startActivity(Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE))
            }
            else {
                permissionState.launchPermissionRequest()
                if (permissionState.status.isGranted) {
                    context.startActivity(Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE))
                }
            }
                  },
        modifier = Modifier.size(90.dp, 60.dp)
    ) {
        Icon(painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.camera), contentDescription = null)
    }



    if (permissionState.status.shouldShowRationale) {
        AlertDialog(
            onDismissRequest = {},
            title = {
                Text(
                    text = "Permission Request",
                    style = TextStyle(
                        //fontSize = MaterialTheme.typography.h6.fontSize,
                        fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold
                    )
                )
            },
            text = {
                Text("Taking photos requires camera permission to run.")
            },
            confirmButton = {
                Button(onClick = {permissionState.launchPermissionRequest()}) {
                    Text("Give Permission")
                }
            }
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To archive 5 point you need to save Boolean property when you already ask for permission using `SharedPreferences` or `Jetpack Datastore` cause there is no other ways to know that the permission was permanently denied

To archive 2 point you need to do something like this:

```
val cameraPermissionState = rememberPermissionState(permission = android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
LaunchedEffect(key1 = cameraPermissionState){
    if (cameraPermissionState.status.isGranted) openCamera()
}
cameraPermissionState.launchPermissionRequest()
```

### Edit 1

The full code to avoid opening camera without clicking on a button:

```
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val cameraPermissionState = rememberPermissionState(permission = CAMERA_PERMISSION)
    var permissionRequested: Boolean by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(false) }

    if (permissionRequested && cameraPermissionState.status.isGranted) {
        permissionRequested = false
        navigateToQrCodeScanner()
    }

Button(
onClick = {
                when {
                    cameraPermissionState.status.isGranted -> {
                        navigateToQrCodeScanner()
                    }

                    cameraPermissionState.status.shouldShowRationale -> {
                        saveCameraPermissionRationaleShown()
                        showCameraPermissionRationaleAlert(false) {
                            permissionRequested = true
                            cameraPermissionState.launchPermissionRequest()
                        }
                    }

                    cameraPermissionRationaleAlreadyShown -> {
                        showCameraPermissionRationaleAlert(true) { context.navigateToAppSettings() }
                    }

                    else -> {
                        permissionRequested = true
                        cameraPermissionState.launchPermissionRequest()
                    }
                }
            }
...
)
```

`showCameraPermissionRationaleAlert` is a parameter of composable function:

```
showCameraPermissionRationaleAlert: (Boolean, (() -> Unit)) -> Unit
```

where `boolean` is a property indicating that the permission has been permanently denied and `lambda` is the action to take when the button in the popup is clicked.

Comment: If I'm right with your ponit. This works the first. But next time I open the app, it activate the camera itself. Because it will execute  if (cameraPermissionState.status.isGranted) openCamera() directly.